# Troubleshooting Circular Audio Player Compatibility on iPhone: Code Analysis

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, html5-audio

I created this circular audio player, and I've included the code below. It functions perfectly as intended for my website. However, I've observed compatibility issues when accessing it from an iPhone. I've provided a link for reference as well. Is there a solution to this problem? Can something be added to the code to ensure it works properly on an iPhone?

Here's the HTML code embedded within a WordPress page:

```
<div id="playerContainer3"></div>

<script>
  // settings
var DEFAULTS = {
    borderColor: "#de6a5a",
    playedColor: "#ffff",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(142,187,196,.1)",
    iconColor: "#de6a5a",
    borderWidth: 1,
    size: 20,
    className: 'circle-audio-player'
};

// reused values
var pi = Math.PI;
var doublePi = pi * 2;
var arcOffset = -pi / 2;
var animTime = 200;
var loaderTime = 1800;

var CircleAudioPlayer3 = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    for (var property in DEFAULTS) {
        this[property] = options[property] || DEFAULTS[property];
    }

    // create some things we need
    this._canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this._canvas.setAttribute('class', this.className + ' is-loading');
    this._canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (function () {
        if (this.playing) {
            this.pause();
        }
        else {
            this.play();
        }
    }).bind(this));
    this._ctx = this._canvas.getContext('2d');

    // set up initial stuff
    this.setAudio(options.audio);
    this.setSize(this.size);

    // redraw loop
    (function cAPAnimationLoop (now) {
        // check if we need to update anything
        if (this.animating) {
            this._updateAnimations(now);
        }
        if (this._forceDraw || this.playing || this.animating || this.loading) {
            this._draw();
            this._forceDraw = false;
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(cAPAnimationLoop.bind(this));
    }).call(this, new Date().getTime());
};
CircleAudioPlayer3.prototype = {
    // private methods
    _animateIcon: function (to, from) {
        // define a few things the first time
        this._animationProps = {
            animStart: null,
            from: from,
            to: to
        };
        if (from) {
            this.animating = true;
        }
        else {
            this._animationProps.current = this._icons[to].slice();
            this.draw();
        }
    },
    _updateAnimations: function (now) {
        this._animationProps.animStart = this._animationProps.animStart || now;
        var deltaTime = now - this._animationProps.animStart;
        var perc = (1 - Math.cos(deltaTime / animTime * pi / 2));
        if (deltaTime >= animTime) {
            this.animating = false;
            perc = 1;
            this._animationProps.current = this._icons[this._animationProps.to].slice();
            this.draw();
        }
        else {
            var from = this._icons[this._animationProps.from];
            var current = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
                current.push([]);
                for (var j = 0; j < from[i].length; j++) {
                    current[i].push([]);
                    var to = this._icons[this._animationProps.to][i][j];
                    current[i][j][0] = from[i][j][0] + (to[0] - from[i][j][0]) * perc;
                    current[i][j][1] = from[i][j][1] + (to[1] - from[i][j][1]) * perc;
                }
            }
            this._animationProps.current = current;
        }
    },
    _draw: function (progress) {
        // common settings
        if (isNaN(progress)) {
            progress = this.audio.currentTime / this.audio.duration || 0;
        }

        // clear existing
        this._ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.size, this.size);

        // draw bg
        this._ctx.beginPath();
        this._ctx.arc(this._halfSize, this._halfSize, this._halfSize - (this.borderWidth / 2), 0, doublePi);
        this._ctx.closePath();
        this._ctx.fillStyle = this.backgroundColor;
        this._ctx.fill();

        // draw border
        // our active path is already the full circle, so just stroke it
        this._ctx.lineWidth = this.borderWidth;
        this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.borderColor;
        this._ctx.stroke();

        // play progress
        if (progress > 0) {
            this._ctx.beginPath();
            this._ctx.arc(this._halfSize, this._halfSize, this._halfSize - (this.borderWidth / 2), arcOffset, arcOffset + doublePi * progress);
            this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.playedColor;
            this._ctx.stroke();
        }

        // icons
        this._ctx.fillStyle = this.iconColor;
        if (this.loading) {
            var loaderOffset = -Math.cos((new Date().getTime() % (loaderTime)) / (loaderTime) * pi) * doublePi - (pi / 2) - (pi / 2);
            this._ctx.beginPath();
            this._ctx.arc(this._halfSize, this._halfSize, this._halfSize / 3, loaderOffset, loaderOffset + pi / 3 * 2);
            this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.iconColor;
            this._ctx.stroke();
        }
        else {
            this._ctx.beginPath();
            var icon = (this._animationProps && this._animationProps.current) || this._icons.play;
            for (var i = 0; i < icon.length; i++) {
                this._ctx.moveTo(icon[i][0][0], icon[i][0][1]);

                for (var j = 1; j < icon[i].length; j++) {
                    this._ctx.lineTo(icon[i][j][0], icon[i][j][1]);
                }
            }

            // this._ctx.closePath();
            this._ctx.fill();
            // stroke to fill in for retina
            this._ctx.strokeStyle = this.iconColor;
            this._ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            this._ctx.lineJoin = 'miter';
            this._ctx.stroke();
        }
    },
    _setState: function (state) {
        this.playing = false;
        this.loading = false;
        if (state === 'playing') {
            this.playing = true;
            this._animateIcon('pause', 'play');
        }
        else if (state === 'loading') {
            this.loading = true;
        }
        else if (this.state !== 'loading') {
            this._animateIcon('play', 'pause');
        }
        else {
            this._animateIcon('play', null);
        }
        this.state = state;
        this._canvas.setAttribute('class', this.className + ' is-' + state);
        this.draw();
    },
    // public methods
    draw: function () {
        this._forceDraw = true;
    },
    setSize: function (size) {
        this.size = size;
        this._halfSize = size / 2; // we do this a lot. it's not heavy, but why repeat?
        this._canvas.width = size;
        this._canvas.height = size;
        // set icon paths
        var iconSize = this.size / 4;
        var pauseGap = iconSize / 10;
        var playLeft = Math.cos(pi / 3 * 2) * (iconSize / 2) + this._halfSize;
        var playRight = iconSize / 2 + this._halfSize;
        var playHalf = (playRight - playLeft) / 2 + playLeft;
        var top = this._halfSize - Math.sin(pi / 3 * 2) * (iconSize / 2);
        var bottom = this.size - top;
        var pauseLeft = this._halfSize - iconSize / 3;
        var pauseRight = this.size - pauseLeft;
        this._icons = {
            play: [
                [
                    [playLeft, top],
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + top],
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + this._halfSize],
                    [playLeft, bottom]
                ],
                [
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + top],
                    [playRight, this._halfSize],
                    [playRight, this._halfSize],
                    [playHalf, (this._halfSize - top) / 2 + this._halfSize]
                ]
            ],
            pause: [
                [
                    [pauseLeft, top + pauseGap],
                    [this._halfSize - pauseGap, top + pauseGap],
                    [this._halfSize - pauseGap, bottom - pauseGap],
                    [pauseLeft, bottom - pauseGap]
                ],
                [
                    [this._halfSize + pauseGap, top + pauseGap],
                    [pauseRight, top + pauseGap],
                    [pauseRight, bottom - pauseGap],
                    [this._halfSize + pauseGap, bottom - pauseGap]
                ]
            ]
        };

        if (this._animationProps && this._animationProps.current) {
            this._animateIcon(this._animationProps.to);
        }
        if (!this.playing) {
            this.draw();
        }
    },
    setAudio: function (audioUrl) {
        this.audio = new Audio(audioUrl);
        this._setState('loading');

        this.audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (function () {
            this._setState('paused');
        }).bind(this));
        this.audio.addEventListener('play', (function () {
            this._setState('playing');
        }).bind(this));
        this.audio.addEventListener('pause', (function () {
            // reset when finished
            if (this.audio.currentTime === this.audio.duration) {
                this.audio.currentTime = 0;
            }
            this._setState('paused');
        }).bind(this));
    },
    appendTo: function (element) {
        element.appendChild(this._canvas);
    },
    play: function () {
        this.audio.play();
    },
    pause: function () {
        this.audio.pause();
    }
};


// now init one as an example
var cap = new CircleAudioPlayer3({
    audio: 'https://brandmozart.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/5-Il-setaccio.mp3',
  size: 50,
  borderWidth: 2
});
cap.appendTo(playerContainer3);
</script>
```

css code:

```
.circle-audio-player {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#playerContainer3 {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

link audio player circular in site:

https://brandmozart.com/hotel/

I've attempted a few solutions, but I've been unable to achieve proper functionality on the iPhone. Your assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.